# Sum up counts in subquery

Tags: sql-server, group-by, duplication

I am writing a query to check if I have got duplicates in a certain column.

```
SELECT COUNT(thecol) FROM thetable WHERE thecol IS NOT NULL GROUP BY thecol 
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

That will give me an output like

```
3
5
6
```

Which of course is the number of records for each value of thecol where thecol is not unique.

Now how do I only get the sum 14? Should I have the existing query as a subquery?

Comment: Since you only count rows where `thecol` values are not null, `COUNT(thecol)` and `COUNT(*)` are inetrchangeable. No need to use both as it looks like they are counting something different.

Comment: I use this to diagnose duplicates in the database that should have been constrained from the start.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT 
    total = 
        SUM(x.records)
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        records = 
            COUNT_BIG(thecol)
    FROM thetable 
    WHERE thecol IS NOT NULL 
    GROUP BY thecol 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS x;
```

Answer (score 3):

Another method which requires that the table has another column (with a `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE NOT NULL` constraint). Lets call it `id`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM thetable AS t
WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT 1
        FROM thetable AS t2
        WHERE t2.thecol = t.thecol
          AND t2.id <> t.id
      ) ;
```